# jsoup fails to return complete node with all children

Tags: java, parsing, nested, jsoup, element

I have a sample html as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/loose.dtd">
 <html lang="en">
<head>
<title>example.com</title>
</head>
<body>

<div>
    <ul class="mb10">
        <li><input class="ript" name="pmtmthd" value="NOLINK"
            type="radio" id="NOLINK" reqType="ChgPaymentMtd" nodsb="true">
            <label for="NOLINK"><img
                src="https://example.com/example1.gif"
                height="23" width="147" alt="Credit Card">
                <div class="v10777" style="margin-left: 20px">Processed</div> 
          </label> </input>
        </li>
        <li><input class="ript" name="pmtmthd" value="SPLLINK"
            type="radio" id="SPLLINK" reqType="ChgPaymentMtd" nodsb="true"
            checked="checked"> <label for="SPLLINK"><img
                src="https://example.com/example2.gif"
                height="19" width="73" alt="spllink">
                </label> </input>
        </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to extract all radio elements:

```
List<Element> radioElements = doc.getElementsByAttributeValue("type", "radio");
```

The output is given without any child element information as below:

```
<input class="ript" name="pmtmthd" value="NOLINK" type="radio" id="NOLINK" reqType="ChgPaymentMtd" nodsb="true" />

<input class="ript" name="pmtmthd" value="SPLLINK" type="radio" id="SPLLINK" reqType="ChgPaymentMtd" nodsb="true" checked="checked" />
```

How can I get all the radio elements with all their children intact?

Answer (score 1):

Jsoup tries to normalize the html so it can correct any wrongdoings (invalid html). Placing something inside the `input` tag is invalid html (`input` is a self closing element, no children are allowed, only attributes) so it removes it. If you want to prevent this normalizing from happening use a different parser like this.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html, "", Parser.xmlParser());
Elements radios = doc.getElementsByAttributeValue("type", "radio");
System.out.println(radios);
```

**Output**

```
<input class="ript" name="pmtmthd" value="NOLINK" type="radio" id="NOLINK" reqtype="ChgPaymentMtd" nodsb="true"><label for="NOLINK"><img src="https://example.com/example1.gif" height="23" width="147" alt="Credit Card">
   <div class="v10777" style="margin-left: 20px">
    Processed
   </div></img></label></input>
<input class="ript" name="pmtmthd" value="SPLLINK" type="radio" id="SPLLINK" reqtype="ChgPaymentMtd" nodsb="true" checked="checked"><label for="SPLLINK"><img src="https://example.com/example2.gif" height="19" width="73" alt="spllink" /></label></input>
```